# Stale output in nagios for Esxi check

Tags: esxi, nagios

I have written a simple shell script that detects the invalid login attempts on Esxi(5.1) server and prints the output on screen as IPs with no of connections with failed attempts.

The script is working fine on Esxi server. But when I'm trying to execute the script from monitoring server (nagios) using check by ssh, I'm getting stale output.

Comment: Don't do it this way. On ESXi ssh should only be enabled temporarily for troubleshooting, but not permanently for monitoring or other purposes!    What you are trying to do should be better achieved by having ESXi send its logs to a syslog server and examine them there with suitable Nagios plugins.

Comment: @VFrontDe I am aware of the method that you have metioned. I am just wondering if this is expected behavior while executing sh script remotely.